# Downloading older podcasts in iTunes

Tags: itunes, rss, podcasts

I subscribe to a number of BBC podcasts. iTunes only lists the 10 most recent, but I want to go back further.

How can I see older podcasts? Is this possible in iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

Go directly to the [BBC website for podcasts](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts) and search there. If not on the BBC site I would imagine it's not available.